# vsftpd: users can delete other users files

Tags: linux, ftp

I'm installed vsftpd ftp daemon. Virtual users shares same root directory. But user can delete other user files. How to disable this ? Any configuration setting? Permissions of uploaded file is 644.

Thanks.

Comment: In UNIX, delete permissions are controlled by the mode of the **directory** the file is in, not the mode of the file itself.  What's the mode of the directory in question?

Comment: Thanks for quick replay. Now I have ftp root directory permissions 747. If I disable OTHER permissions I can't upload anything with FTP program. Because OTHER permissions is 7. So ftp program can delete files no matter which user and which group is :/

Comment: In a directory with other-write, generally, anyone can delete any file.

Comment: I'm using virtual users. And looks my FTP program uploads/deletes files with OTHER permissions. So I removed root folder permission for others to write and now I can't create/delete files by ftp client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to have multiple users writing to the same directory, and don't want them to be able to delete each other's files, set the sticky bit on the directory. This is the same mode set on `/tmp` to restrict that directory in the same way.

```
chmod 1777 /var/ftp/freeforall
```